# How are Prophete chains with built-in locks assembled?

Tags: maintenance, chain, installation

I recently bought a 3/32" chain from Prophete, and despaired in the attempt to close it. The complex end of the chain looks like this:

[image: Photo of the Prophete chain link]

Now, at first thought, the slight groove (the one where you can peek the Euro sign) looks designed to take the bolt, and then pressure during riding will close the link. Unfortunately, the open part of the link is too short for the bolt to fit. Whenever I slide the upper part over the lower part, I have to bend it slightly, and the bolt misses the groove by half a bolt diameter.

How in the world should I assemble this?

Comment: There's just *one* special plate that looks like that? Not *two*?

Comment: Yes, there is just this one special plate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move the open end of the posts closer together so you can pop that plate into place. To do that, bend the chain sideways at that master link to get it to close.

There's a bit of technique, but it's not too hard to close (opening it again often requires three hands - the extra one to lift the plate off. Sometimes the plate will pop off if you bend the chain a bit further, sometimes not).

1. Move the slotted plate so it's over the post ready to close.
2. Hold the chain with one hand each side of the master link with the slotted plate towards you.
3. Pull your hands apart slightly so that the chain is straight.
4. Now bend the chain so the master link moves away from you (and the open end of those posts get closer together).

It might take a couple of attempts but it can be done (the chain-bending is the same way I push chain into chain tubes on my recumbents, when I can't life the recumbent to get the tube vertical)